# What is the correct way to run a function every time a specific template is rendered?

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

From digging around it seems that `Template.myTemplate.rendered` used to fulfil this functionality but since it's been replace with `Template.myTemplate.onRendered` it only runs once, when the template is initially rendered.

I tried to hack this functionality by adding a helper function and calling it from the template but this wasn't a satisfactory solution for me because it fires before the template has rendered (for obvious reasons).

Is there a hook I can use to register a function once a specific template has loaded?

Comment: can you be more specific on what you mean by "loaded"? that sounds like onRendered to me. Do you mean, every time the template appears on the page (even after it has been hidden, say when a different tab was opened?)

Comment: `onRendered` does what you *say* you want but you must mean something else.

Comment: Perhaps what I'm looking for has more to do with the router. I have a route that renders a template, if you navigate away from this template and back to it the information may have changed so I would like to be able to run the function each time the template is shown. Currently, using `onRendered` the function is only called the first time the template is rendered which seems to be the expected behaviour as per the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about this, I've just realised that `onRendered` is indeed the correct way of doing this because when I use it for other templates it behaves as I want it to i.e. it fires every time the template is rendered. The reason it is only called once for this particular template is because it is in a modal and only hidden/shown after it's first rendered rather than being re-rendered every time the route is hit.